# How to play audio in the background of a UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I created a media player app using UWP for Windows 10. Currently I cannot play any audio in the background, when I minimize my media player window the audio stops playing and resumes when I maximize the window. This is my media element XAML code I used:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="PlayerElement" Height="532" Width="829" 
                            AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" PosterSource="/Images/Logo3.png" 
                          AutoPlay="True" MediaEnded="PlayNewSong" Margin="0,0,-9,0" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"/>
```

I thought the AudioCategory property would solve my problem, but unfortunately it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120489/whats-the-easiest-way-to-play-audio-in-background-in-uwp

Comment: I did that and it didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Check this official sample collection from microsoft [WindowsUniversalSamples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples)

You can pull **BackgroundMediaPlayback** folder for sample project you need.

Comment: artista_14 is correct. There is the samples link provided above and the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio